# Why do my dropdown menus appear behind my background image for body?

Tags: css, html

I built a horizontal menu with dropdown menus under each category. I know in general my website coding has been unorganized, but the main issue is why the dropdown menus are obscured by a wrapper I have above the main content of my page. In the jsfiddle it would be behind the "Uganda" and extend across the page. Whenever I open a dropdown menu however, the dropdown goes behind the wrapper despite it being classified as a background-image in my css.

https://jsfiddle.net/pr8kexmt/

```css
a {
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  padding: 12px 16px;
}

body {
  margin: 0px;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.bodycontent {
  z-index: -1;
}

.content {
  font-family: verdana;
  font-size: 30px;
}

.donate {
  background-color: orange;
  border: white;
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  padding: 7px 14px;
  font-size: 15px;
  border-radius: 8px;
}

.donate:hover {
  background-color: rgb(102, 51, 0);
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}

.divnav {
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.dropbtn {
  font-size: 13px;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  background-color: inherit;
  float: right;
  display: block;
  margin: 3px 3px 3px 3px;
  font-family: verdana;
  font-weight: 550;
}

.dropbtn:hover {
  color: orange;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 1;
  overflow: auto;
  top: 100%;
}

.dropdown-contentblock {
  height: 20px;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}

html {}

.image {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.navbar {
  width: 80%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  text-align: center;
}

.navelement {
  float: right;
  display: block;
  margin: 3px 3px 3px 3px;
  font-family: verdana;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-weight: 550;
}

.nava {
  padding: 5px;
}

.nava:hover {
  background-color: white;
  color: orange;
}

.pagetitle {
  height: 68px;
  width: 100%;
  background-image: url("pictures/titlebar1.jpg");
  z-index: -10;
}

.par {
  /* DIV THAT GOES UNDER TODOCONTENT ONLY AND MARKS A PARAGRAPH WITH INFORMATIVE CONTENT*/
}

.parcontent {
  font-family: verdana;
  color: rgb(150, 150, 150);
  font-size: 15px;
}

.titleimage {
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 310px;
  margin: 0px;
  width: 100%;
}

.title {
  font-family: verdana;
  font-size: 50px;
  color: white;
}

.todocontent {
  width: 47%;
  /* A DIV WITH CLASS TODOCONTENT MEANS A DIV THAT WILL CONTAIN ALL INFORMATIVE CONTENT OF THE PAGE*/
}

.wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 5%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="titleimage">
  <img src="file:///Users/kirannairrl/Desktop/KiranNairRL/internship/current/pictures/heading2.jpg" alt="GLI.logo" style="width:100%;height:100%;">
</div>
<div class="divnav">
  <div class="wrapper" style="POSITION: absolute; TOP: 300px; LEFT: 0px;">
    <img src="file:///Users/kirannairrl/Desktop/KiranNairRL/internship/current/pictures/wrapper.png" alt="wrapper" style="width:20000px;height:5px;">
  </div>
  <div style="POSITION: relative; TOP: 20px; LEFT: 15%;">
    <img src="file:///Users/kirannairrl/Desktop/KiranNairRL/internship/current/pictures/GLI.logo.png" alt="GLI.logo" style="width:145px;height:152px;">
  </div>
  <div style="POSITION: relative; TOP: -50px; LEFT: 10%;">
    <ul class="navbar">
      <div class="dropdown">
        <button class="dropbtn">HOME</button>
        <!--<div class="dropdown-content">
     <a href="#">HOME</a>
    </div>-->
      </div>
      <div class="dropdown">
        <button class="dropbtn">ABOUT</button>
        <div class="dropdown-content">
          <a href="#">Vision & Mission</a>
          <a href="#">What We Do</a>
          <a href="#">Our Story</a>
          <a href="#">GLI Leadership</a>
          <a href="#">Academic Partners</a>
          <a href="#">Annual Report</a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="dropdown">
        <button class="dropbtn">PROGRAMS</button>
        <div class="dropdown-content">
          <a href="#">Immersion Trips</a>
          <a href="#">Internships</a>
          <a href="#">IKnow Concert Series</a>
          <a href="#">Women's Leadership Retreat</a>
          <a href="#">Youth Summit</a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="dropdown">
        <button class="dropbtn">ENTUSI</button>
        <div class="dropdown-content">
          <a href="#">About Entusi</a>
          <a href="#">Entusi Leadership</a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="dropdown">
        <button class="dropbtn">MEDIA</button>
        <div class="dropdown-content">
          <a href="#">Press</a>
          <a href="#">Blog</a>
          <a href="#">Videos</a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="dropdown">
        <button class="dropbtn">UPCOMING EVENTS</button>
        <!--<div class="dropdown-content">
     <a href="#">UPCOMING EVENTS</a>
    </div>-->
      </div>
      <div class="dropdown">
        <button class="dropbtn">TRIP PREP</button>
        <div class="dropdown-content">
          <a href="#">Orientational Materials</a>
          <a href="#">F.A.Q.</a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="dropdown">
        <button class="dropbtn">RESEARCH</button>
        <div class="dropdown-content">
          <a href="#">Articles</a>
          <a href="#">Capstones</a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="dropdown">
        <button class="dropbtn">CONTACT</button>
        <!--<div class="dropdown-content">
     <a href="#">CONTACT</a>
    </div>-->
      </div>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="divdonate" style="POSITION: relative; TOP: -140px; LEFT: 80%;">
    <button class="donate">DONATE NOW</button>
  </div>
</div>

<body>

  <div class="bodycontent">
    <div class="pagetitle">
      <div>
        <header class="title" style="POSITION: relative; LEFT: 15%">Uganda</header>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="todocontent" style="POSItiON: relative; TOP: 15%; LEFT: 15%;">
      <div class="par" style="POSITION: relative; TOP: 15%; LEFT: 0%;">
        <p class="parcontent">
          Uganda was formed from the colonization of the Buganda Kingdom by the British in the 19th century. Britain wanted to protect the viability of the Nile River for its trading potential which prompted the British government to annex Buganda to create the
          Uganda Protectorate in 1894. In 1962 Uganda regained its independence and declared itself a republic with Milton Obote as the first prime minister and former Bugandan King Muteesa as the president. Despite being largely ceremonial, Obote removed
          the presidential position and established a new constitution in which he became a powerful president similar to a dictator. After committing many atrocities Obote was removed from power in a coup orchestrated by General Idi Amin who seized control
          of the country. Amin proceeded to be nearly as atrocious as Obote when almost 500,000 citizens perished under his regime. Despite entering presidency with cheers, his actions made the country of Uganda hate him. After Amin was removed from power
          by largely Tanzanian forces, Obote returned to presidency. A war broke out as a result from the election resulting in the deaths of between 100 and 500,000 people. This compelled 2 military commanders to conduct a coup in which Museveni gained
          control. Yoweri Museveni remains in power till this date.
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Ideally you don't want to shove elements around the way you have with relative and absolute positioning - float them, flexbox them or inline them instead. Also, there's no need to tell block level elements like `div` to be `width: 100%;` as their default is to take up 100% the width of their parent element. Also, most instances of your `z-index` are unnecessary, `z-index` doesn't work unless you position the element or give it a flex context.

Answer (score 3):

It's because of this

```
.divnav {
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

it really needs to be overflow hidden? if you remove it, works fine

Comment: Exactly. Why is he hiding the overflow ?

Comment: I don't have ideia

Comment: I thought it might have been for clearing floats, nope, not for that. But if you look at the rest of the CSS it's easy to see that it was probably something that was _"tossed in"_ to try and _"make it work."_ As it stands, OP could remove `.divnav` altogether. Once `overflow: hidden;` is removed it's useless.

Comment: Sorry like I said I'm pretty to new to html my organization/coding in general is pretty bad. Thanks for the help though guys I appreciate it :)